# Jquery Change background color of DIV to #333 only when all checkbox is not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 `div` with `class .thumb-folder` and inside each contains a `checkbox`.
I also have another `div` with a class `.alarm`.

When 1 or many `checkboxes` is checked the `div` with `.alarm class` changes background to red.

How to change the `div` with the `.alarm class` to `background #333` only when no `checkboxes` are checked?

Here is [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/bhykT/) to jsfiddle of my current code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the sam eselector you used to bind the handler to check if any checkboxes are checked.

```
  $('.thumb-folder input:checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
      if ($('.thumb-folder input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $('div.alarm').css("background-color","red");
      } 
    else{
        $('div.alarm').css("background-color","#333");
      }
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/bhykT/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use length to find the checked checkbox count using `:checked`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/bhykT/5/)**

```
$('.thumb-folder input:checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
  if ($('.thumb-folder :checked').length == 0)
     $('div.alarm').css("background-color", "#333");
  else 
     $('div.alarm').css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do this in 3 lines:

```
 $('.thumb-folder input:checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
        $('div.alarm').css("background-color",(($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 0) ? "red" : "#333"));
  });
```